# rsync run from bash script not preserving ownership

Tags: bash, eval, rsync

I'm trying to create a bash script which will sync a directory specified as a command line parameter to a remote server (also specified by a parameter). At the moment, I'm using `eval`, which solves a parameter expansion problem, but for some reason causes rsync not to preserve ownership on the remote files (apart from being Evil, I know). Running the rsync command with all the same flags and parameters from the command prompt works fine.

I tried using `$()` as an alternative, but I got into a real mess with variable expansion and protecting the bits that need protecting for the remote rsync path (which needs both quotes *and* backslashes for paths with spaces).

So - I guess 2 questions - is there a reason that `eval` is preventing `rsync` from preserving ownership (the bash script is being run as root on the source machine, and `ssh`ing to the remote machine as root too - just for now)? And is there a way of getting `$()` to work in this scenario? The (trimmed) code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

RSYNC_CMD="/usr/bin/rsync"
RSYNC_FLAGS="-az --rsh=\"/usr/bin/ssh -i \${DST_KEY}\""  # Protect ${DST_KEY} until it is assigned later

SRC=${1}  # Normally this is sense checked and processed to be a canonical path

# Logic for setting DST based on command line parameter snipped for clarity - just directly assign for testing

DST='root@some.server.com:'
DST_KEY='/path/to/sshKey.rsa'

TARG=${DST}${SRC//' '/'\ '}  # Escape whitespace for target system

eval ${RSYNC_CMD} ${RSYNC_FLAGS} \"${SRC}\" \"${TARG}\"  # Put quotes round the paths - even though ${TARG} is already escaped

# All synced OK - but ownership not preserved despite -a flag
```

I've tried changing `RSYNC_CMD` to `sudo /usr/bin/rsync`, and also adding `--rsync-path="sudo /usr/bin/rsync` to `RSYNC_FLAGS`, but neither made any difference. I just can't see what I'm missing...

Comment: `rsync --help | grep owner` tells me: `-o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)`. Did you try that option?

Comment: Thanks - as @chepner said below, -a implies -o, and if I do it from the command line, it works fine, so I'd presumed it was the eval (just to be sure, I did try -o, but no difference). I'm going to give chepner's rewrite a go in the next few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use an array. `-a` should already imply `-o`.

```
RSYNC_CMD="/usr/bin/rsync"

DST='root@some.server.com:'
DST_KEY='/path/to/sshKey.rsa'

RSYNC_FLAGS=(-az --rsh="/usr/bin/ssh -i ${DST_KEY}")

SRC=${1}
TARG="${DST}$SRC"

${RSYNC_CMD} "${RSYNC_FLAGS[@]}" "${SRC}" "${TARG}"
```

Using `RSYNC_RSH` instead of `--rsh`, you can export the variable before you set its value. This at least lets you put the export in the same area where you set the rest of the flags. Then you can defer completing its value until after you have the correct identity file.

```
RSYNC_CMD="/usr/bin/rsync"
export RSYNC_RSH="/usr/bin/ssh -i %s"  # Use a placeholder for now; set it later
RSYNC_FLAGS=( -a -z )

# Later...

DST='root@some.server.com:'
DST_KEY='/path/to/sshKey.rsa'
RSYNC_RSH=$( printf "$RSYNC_RSH" "$DST_KEY" )


SRC=${1}
TARG="${DST}$SRC"

${RSYNC_CMD} "${RSYNC_FLAGS[@]}" "${SRC}" "${TARG}"
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm away for a few days, so can't try directly, but in the meantime, is it possible to set `DST_KEY` *after* `RSYNC_FLAGS`, as in my original code using your method? I like to have all the flags defined at the top, but this one needs to include the computed `DST_KEY` - which `eval` was then expanding as needed.

Comment: I don't recommend using `eval`, as it can be a security risk. One other option is to use the `RSYNC_RSH` environment variable. It would still require setting its value later in the process, but I'll update my answer with an example of how to do so "cleanly".

Comment: The update is a bit ugly. What determines the value of `DST_KEY`? It might be possible to set up a site-specific identity file in `.ssh/config`; then you wouldn't need the `-i` flag for `ssh` at all.

Comment: The idea is to call the script and pass an identifier (e.g. 'dev'), from which the script looks up the correct hostname and .rsa file. That way the user doesn't need to know those.

I know I could just set the `RSYNC_FLAGS` after setting up `DST` and `DST_KEY` - but in general I was wondering if there was a way to reapply variable expansion without using eval.

Comment: Great - that worked perfectly, and got rid of many annoying `\"` sequences! I didn't use an array for the `RSYNC_FLAGS` in the end - just a straight string, but it didn't seem to matter... I've also concluded that repeated expansion isn't possible (based on other SO posts I've read), and the only choice is `eval`. I guess I was just lucky that `rsync` reads that particular environment variable :)

But I still can't work out why the original version using `eval` caused the ownership preservation to fail...